# Java Deck of Cards Iterator<Cards> method

Tags: java, iterator, shuffle

I have a `Card` class and a `Deck` class and a method I am supposed to implement is the following:

> `Iterator<Card> iterator ( )`
>   Returns the standard `Iterator<Deck>` (do this by either delegating to the data-type that you used to contain Cards, or by defining an inner-class that exposes this interface—your call.

My question is: What does it mean to delegate a data type? And how do I approach that?

Comment: This means that the `Deck` class should implement `Iterator<Card>`.

Comment: My  `Deck` class does implement that, what should the method return though?

Comment: Probably `return this`?